# Maven Installation - could not find org.codehaus.plexus.classoworlds.launcher.Launcher

Tags: java, apache, maven

I have access to maven through Netbeans IDE, but am trying to install Maven 3.5.0 separate so I could install custom jar files into local .m2 repo through command line in cmd.

I have downloaded the zip file for Maven 3.5.0 from 
http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

**file : apache-maven-3.5.0-src.zip**

When I tried executing the command

```
mvn -v
```

getting this error..

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classwolrds.launcher.Launcher
```

I have already tried various environment variable settings such as

- adding User PATH to the apache maven bin
- adding System PATH to the apache maven bin
- Setting MAVEN_HOME in System to apache maven folder
- Setting M2_HOME and M3_HOME instead of MAVEN_HOME

finally when I tried to run mvn -v from apache maven bin direct

```
c:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0\apache-maven\src\bin>mvn -v
```

still got the same issue, I figure there is a conflict in installation itself.

Comment: What is the value of your `M2_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables?

Comment: Remove `M2_HOME`, `M3_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` from your environment. Only make an entry into the `c:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0\apache-maven\src\bin` nothing else...Furthermore you should not download the source package...you have to download the binary package for windows which is a ZIP file...

Comment: MAVEN_HOME : C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0\apache-maven

PATH : C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\Gradle 3.4.1\gradle-3.4.1\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0\apache-maven\src\bin

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise mvn command seems to be working after fetching the binary file instead of source file, pardon am only into programming for couple of months now. But still I can't seem to execute mvn command else where other than the maven directory.

Comment: No problem. In Windows you need to setup environment variable (Use google for that how to do that) and afterwards you need to reopen the command line and retry it...

Comment: Figured it, working thanks a ton.